# X-axis labels are overlapping when plotting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 115 columns, I want to plot the column names on the x-axis. But the column names are overlapping with each other. The y-axis has single row values.

```
features = fdf.iloc[0] # single row 
features.sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

This is the graph, as you can see that the x-axis labels are not clear.
[image: barplot picturd]

Comment: You simply had too many X labels for the space provided. Solutions include making the chart wider or cutting down the number of labels or split it off into multiple charts. Can you give some example of the X labels? I can't read them from the picture.

Comment: x-labels are columns of the data frame. i have 115  columns. each column string  is aroound 15 character string. as single row contains vlaues of y-axis.   ```[MI_dir_L3_weight
MI_dir_L3_mean
MI_dir_L3_variance
MI_dir_L1_weight
MI_dir_L1_mean
MI_dir_L1_variance
MI_dir_L0.1_weight
MI_dir_L0.1_mean
MI_dir_L0.1_variance
MI_dir_L0.01_weight
MI_dir_L0.01_mean] ``` these are the some x-label strings.

Comment: Thanks for adding the column samples. I think it make most sense to split this into multiple charts. You can split by statistics (all `weight` go into one chart, all `mean` go into another) or by data series (`L3`, `L0.1`, ...)

Answer (score 2):

You have few options :

- make the figure wider using `figsize` argument in `plot`

```
features.sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='bar', figsize = (15, 7))
```

- Reduce the size of xticks label on x axis using `fontsize` argument in `xticks'

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize = 'xx-small')
```

read about more options for `fontsize` [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)